# Protractor e2e when page refresh after click with fresh data

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am fairly new protractor e2e testing.The page under test is a non angular (knockout) page. The test case as follows

A page has a kendo grid loads with default data. but when a check box is clicked, it load with some other data.

I would like to test the scenario, when grid reloads with new data.

`browser.wait(element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent)`  is not suitable, as this element already exists when it has default data. I use   `browser.driver.sleep(2000)` to wait for the page to reload after check box click. But I am sure this explicit wait is not a good idea, can anyone help with this? Any pattern to suggest in this case. Any help of this greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it a full page reload or in the background (ajax)?

Comment: Expected conditions has more conditions than isPresent(): 
https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions
Try some of those, elementToBeClickable, or visibilityOf should work.

Comment: @@ Michael Radionov    its a partial page reload, just the grids dat

Comment: @cvakiitho elementToBeClickable, or visibilityOf cannot work as this element are already on the page before it reloads,

Comment: Well you said there is some data that loads after? so target that data?

Comment: @cvakiitho if I target the new data, the expect would be wrong as it validates the previously loaded data. So it has to wait until the data refreshes,

Comment: @ Michael Radionov  browser.wait(EC.titleContains(x,'foo'), 5000); never be correct unless it waits to load the fresh data

Comment: @Jyothish, I think @ cvakiitho suggested to check for that specific data your are waiting for, if you know what this data is. Not for an element, but a text in the grid. Would not it work? Maybe there is some indicator which becomes visible when you load new data to depend on?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is the new data loaded in the grid, what we can do is *locate the existing row in the grid, click the checkbox and check that the previously located row is now "stale"*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var existingRow = element(by.css("#mygrid tr"));

checkbox.click();

browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(existingRow), 5000);
```

---

Another approach might be to *wait for row count in the grid to change*:

```
element.all(by.css("#mygrid tr")).count().then(function (countBefore) {
    checkbox.click();

    browser.wait(function () {
        return element.all(by.css("#mygrid tr")).count().then(function (countAfter) {
            return countBefore !== countAfter;
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot you said it is non-angular page.

So there is a different set of waits, basically inherited directly from webdriver:
https://github.com/sakshisingla/Protractor-Non-Angular-Tests/wiki/Creating-test-scripts-using-Protractor-for-non-angular-application :
So something like this should work:

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
     return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('some-element'))
              .then(function(elem) {
                <Your test code>
                return true;
              });
  }, 2000);
```